# Magento good practices

Tags: magento-1.8, query

How can I write this same query, but with magento language ?

```
        $table = $resource->getTableName('sales/order');

        $total_quadrante = $readConnection->fetchAll('SELECT base_subtotal FROM ' . $table
        . ' WHERE '
        . ' customer_id = ' . (int)$customerId
        . ' AND (created_at BETWEEN '
        . '"' . $date_begin . '"'
        . ' AND '
        . '"' . $date_end . '"' . ')');
```

And I have this loop to get the sum from the orders from $total_quadrante:

```
    foreach($collection as $child) {
        $gasto += $child['base_subtotal'];
    }
```

Comment: could add the table name.

Comment: Sorry! I edited now

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToSelect('base_subtotal');
$collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('eq'=> $customerId));
$collection->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $date_begin, 'to' => $date_end));
```

I haven't test the code, try and let me know.

Comment: I'll try it, and let you know!

Comment: It doesn't work, I can't get the base_subtotal from it :/

Comment: could show the output for the code?

Comment: From $collection or $gasto ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$collection->addAttributeToSelect('base_subtotal');` on the second line?

Comment: collection output.

Comment: The output it's giant!